# Static method doesn't make change on reference type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, ienumerable

I wrote static method to exclude some items from IEnumerable collection.

```
public static void Exclude(this IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list, params object[] excludeValues)
    {
        list = list.Where(x => excludeValues.All(y => x.Value != y.ToString())).ToList();
    }
```

I have field StatementTypeSource filled already but

```
model.StatementTypeSource.Exclude(1, 2);
```

doesn't make any changes in field. What is interesting, that before ending execution method, list has excluded values, but returning back, in model I still have original collection.
It's important for me to make method void and modify list by reference.

Comment: You'd have to return the list from this method. List is reference type, so the parameter is just reference to the list and your assignment make it point to another list, but original list remains and reference that you have called this method for is still pointing to this. You could do it using "ref" parameter instead of doing extension method.

Comment: You can implement this differently, using a `foreach` on the params and `RemoveAll` on the list. [Demo here.](https://rextester.com/UVIL75364)

Comment: Doesn't 'this' keyword work like ref in this case?
I'm replacing references by assigning new reference to the old one.

Comment: No. `this` does not imply `ref`, and can't be used with `ref` either. What happens in your current implementation is that you're redirecting your parameter reference to a new list - but arguments pass by value, so once your code ran this line, you have two different lists - one that you used when calling the method, and one inside the method (that's going to expire as soon as the method ends)

Comment: @ZoharPeled IEnumerable doesn't implement method RemoveAll

Comment: @Piotr correct. I thought it was a `List<T>`. In that case, you have to return an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: And that's the point, is it possible to handle IEnumerable in that way?

Comment: Using @ZoharPeled idea there is my solution https://rextester.com/GOVOX64582

Comment: Your solution will only work if the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is, in fact, a list - it will not work if it's any other type that implements the `IEnumerable` - in fact, it will throw a `NullReferenceException`. That being said, you can simply change the `this` parameter type from `IEnumeralbe<T>` to `List<T>` - but come to think about it, that would make the entire method an exercise in redundant code, as this can simply be done with the `RemoveAll` and a slightly different predicate.